# A map from a symmetric product of a curve to its Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, fibre-bundles, jacobians

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, of genus $g$.
It is well known that, after fixing a point $p_0$, the map $C^{(n)}\to J$ sending $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ to $[a_1+\dots+a_n-np_0]$, from the n-th symmetric product of the curve to its Jacobian, is an algebraic projective bundle (for $n>2g-2$).

Consider the map $C^{(n)}\times C^{(n)}\to J$, sending $(\{a_1,\dots,a_n\},\{b_1,\dots,b_n\})$ to $[a_1+\dots+a_n-b_1-\dots-b_n]$.

Is this map also a fiber bundle?

Comment: Certainly not. If it was, the induced map on the Albanese variety would be an isomorphism. But $\operatorname{Alb}(C^{(n)}\times C^{(n)})\cong J\times J $.

Comment: I also agree that this is not a "fiber bundle" in the sense of a morphism that, locally on the target, is isomorphic to projection of a product scheme to a factor.  However, I do not see how to deduce this from the Albanese variety (perhaps the fiber itself has nontrivial Albanese isomorphic to $J$).  Rather, I believe that this follows from the fact that the projective bundle $C^{(n)}\to \text{Pic}^n_{C/k}$ is not equivariant for the natural action of $\text{Pic}^0_{C/k}$.  Of course if $k$ equals $\mathbb{C}$, then Ehresmann applies to the underlying differentiable manifolds.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the OP meant projective fiber bundle. I am not sure what he means by "fiber bundle".

Comment: @abx Sorry for the intrusion, but why is $\mathrm{Alb}(C^{(n)}\times C^{(n)})\cong J\times J$? Is in general, $\mathrm{Alb}(C^{(n)})\cong J$? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Alessio: Yes, $\operatorname{Alb}(C^{(n)})\cong J $. Use the fact that the natural map $C^{(n)}\rightarrow J$ induces an isomorphism on $H_1(-,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @abx Thanks for the answer. Sorry, but I don't get your hint, can you spell out a bit more? (Meanwhile I figured out another proof by showing that $J$ satisfies the universal property of $\mathrm{Alb}(C^{(n)})$ but I still would like to understand your approach). I tried to use that $\mathrm{Alb}(X)=\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)^{\vee}$ and the exponential sequence, but I don't see where the isomorphism on $H_1(-,\mathbb{Z})$ comes from and how to apply it.

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't see why $H_1$ is relevant, there is no way I can explain it in a comment. Have a look at the chapter on Riemann surfaces in Griffiths and Harris.

Answer (score 5):

Let $J_n = Pic(C)_n$ --- the moduli space of line bundles of degree $n$ on $C$. Then there is a map
$$
C^{(n)} \to J^n,\qquad \{a_1,\dots,a_n\} \mapsto O(a_1+\dots+a_n).
$$
This is a slightly more canonical version of the map you considered, in particular it is a projective bundle for $n > 2g - 2$.

The map you are interested in can be written as the composition
$$
C^{(n)} \times C^{(n)} \to J_n \times J_n \cong J_n \times J_{-n} \to J_0.
$$
Here the first map is the product of to projective bundles (its fiber is a product of two projective spaces), the second is an isomorphism (given by dualization of a line bundle in the second factor), and the third is a (trivial) abelian fibration.

So, altogether, the fibers of your map are fiber products of two projective bundles over an abelian variety.

Comment: I see why the fiber is the product of two projective spaces, but why do we have local triviality?

Comment: @user4231: Local triviality of what?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question. Arthur Mattuck, in his article “Picard bundle”, showed that $C^{(n)}\to J$ is a projective fiber bundle in the sense of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle. My question is, is the map that I gave a fiber bundle in that sense?

Comment: @user4231: I am not sure it is locally trivial, but each component, $C^{(n)} \times C^{(n)} \to J_n \times J_n$ and $J_n \times J_n \to J_0$, is locally trivial.

Comment: That is not locally trivial.  That is what my comment was about.  If you pullback the projective bundle by a general translation, it is a non-isomorphic projective bundle.